# Java technologies that support transaction processing

Tags: java

i got this exam question that was about Java technologies that support transaction processing, and the answers were:

**a. RMI
 b. CORBA
 c. JTS
 d. JMAPI
 e. JDBC**

and i was confused between: **a. RMI b. CORBA c. JTS** and **a. RMI d. JMAPI e. JDBC**

please advise what is the correct answer, thanks.

Comment: Did you try [looking up `JTS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_transaction_service)?

Comment: have you tried google? Perhaps you should do a minimum amount of research if this is an exam question! I'll give you a clue, look at what the acronyms actually mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**b) CORBA, c) JTS** and **e) JDBC** support transactions.

RMI can't support transaction (How would you roll back a method invocation?). I assume that JTS = Java Transaction Service, as part of JTA (Java Transaction API).

JMAPI seems to be the Java Mail API. Mail protocols do not support transactions either afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer is [JTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_transaction_service).

But others ([JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation)) may also provide transaction services directly/indirectly.